# Custom regional language

Tags: c

I am writing code in C using 8051 MC at89c51 family to display a regional language in 16x2 lcd displayer.

Because the lcd doesn't read regional languages by default, I create the custom character and I converted each letter into hex. But what I don't understand is where I can put the converted hex value in my code and display as I want?

```
void main()
{
...
str_lcd("HELLO & WELCOME"); 
delay_ms(3000);
cmd_lcd(0x80);
cmd_lcd(0x01);
...
}
```

for "HELLO & WELCOME" the hex value is...

```
{0x40,0x60,0x30,0x1c,0x14,0x14,0x14,0x14},
{0x78,0x08,0x10,0x20,0x18,0x08,0x08,0x08},
{0x20,0x40,0x7c,0x24,0x24,0x04,0x0a,0x11},
{0x78,0x08,0x10,0x20,0x18,0x08,0x08,0x08},

{0x38,0x28,0x38,0x10,0x38,0x28,0x28,0x28},
{0x44,0x44,0x64,0x24,0x24,0x24,0x24,0x3c},
{0x3c,0x40,0x40,0x20,0x18,0x08,0x08,0x08},

{0x00,0x7f,0x55,0x55,0x55,0x55,0x77,0x00},
{0x7c,0x54,0x54,0x54,0x04,0x04,0x04,0x04},
{0x7c,0x10,0x1c,0x04,0x1f,0x04,0x04,0x04},
{0x48,0x48,0x48,0x4e,0x48,0x48,0x48,0x78},  
};
```

so can any one help me where I can put this hex value and display it on the lcd?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each 8-byte array corresponds to a specific character, you could have a table of 128 such 8-byte arrays anywhere in the code, for example by having a static array of arrays of constant bytes, like

```
static const unsigned char character_data[128][8] = {
    // Your data here, one entry per character
};
```

Most of the data in the table above would simply be zero.

Now *where* you put this table doesn't really matter, the compiler and linker will make sure it ends up in the correct segment (most likely in the `text` segment with the code). But since I declared it as `static` it should be placed in the source file which does the translation between the characters and the data sent to the LCD panel.

Comment: thank you but am not sure if i understand what you mean, earlier i tried it like this str_lcd("HELLO & WELCOME"); static const unsigned char character_data[128][8] = { // Your data here, one entry per character, i insert the hex value here }; delay_ms(3000); cmd_lcd(0x80); cmd_lcd(0x01); or do u mean i put the hex on the str_lcd("") ? i thought i should create a .h and .cpp file –